# lasagna sauce ahead of time

Tags: sauce, lasagna

I know it is possible to make lasagna a day or so ahead of time but I would like to make only the sauce ahead of time, let it cool and then refrigerate. Then bake the lasagna the next day. Any thought on this?

Comment: if you want to anticipate the assembly as well, you can and here's an old discussion about it https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/can-you-assemble-lasagna-one-day-and-then-bake-it-about-24-hrs-later?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make the tomato (or meat) sauce in advance and keep it a few days in the fridge.

You can also make the bechamel in advance and keep it in the fridge.

Comment: It also freezes well.  There is always at least one quart container of basic tomato sauce in my freezer.